How to scale an object with a reference object in the scan
I'm working on getting many scan of different very young plants to which I need to associate a reference scale object of known dimentions to be able to get the correct dimention of the plant when importing it in Blender for later analysis (like calculating volume, area, etc.)
At the moment I'm using a pot tag 1cm wide and I'm trying to use that dimention to scale the whole model.
I'm still very new to Blender and I want to ask if someone has already tried something similar, which object as scale reference work best, and how to report the correct dimentions to scale the plant in Blender?


Yea I do something similar, tho with smaller objects. You can just spawn a plane that is 1cm and align it to the tag with snap to surface. Then scale the plant until the tag matches the size of the plane. It's easier if you use the Cursor as the pivot point so you can, for example, align one of the corners of the tag and the plane, put the cursor roughly there and scale and rotate the object from that cursor.

I'm not sure if you've noticed but each object has Dimensions property that you can set directly -- which will then change the Scale property accordingly.  I'm not sure which object you previously selected in your screencap:  I see 0.06 meters tall (Z-axis) in your Dimensions.   This should be the bounds of your object.  Adjust one for height (for example) and then copy/past that Z-scale to the X & Y scales.

Hi Alsaac, please avoid using the "need moderator intervention" flag for comments that you believe are incorrect or do not answer your question. You can easily address these situations by replying to the comment and explaining or clarifying why their response may not address the problem. For more information on appropriate uses of the moderator flag, please refer to this resource: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10848/what-are-acceptable-reasons-for-flagging-as-requires-moderator-attention
